# Why vegetarian food is considered to be the best food?

Tags: health, is-it-vegetarian, living-with-omnivores

A vegetarian diet is high in fiber, vitamins, minerals and low in saturated fats. This keeps your blood pressure and cholesterol levels in check. Over-time, regular consumption of such a diet can lower your risk of heart diseases and stroke.

Comment: Welcome Nguyen! It sounds like you are trying to answer your own question that was only posed in the title.  Take a look around the site, and you'll be able to learn about our format.  Thanks!